# Add constraint on resetting password

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, php-5.6, symfony-2.8

I want to add constraint on password on my Symfony2.8 project. The first constraint I'm trying to create is a minimum length for password.

At the moment I've only implemented the reseting password functionnality with the mail for lost password.

So what I did is create a `validation.xml` file in `MyUsersBundle/Resources/config`

```
<constraint-mapping xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping
        http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping/constraint-mapping-1.0.xsd">
    <!--
 ! Password Constraint
 !-->
    <class name="FOS\UserBundle\Form\Model\ChangePassword">
        <property name="plainPassword">
<constraint name="Length">
                <option name="min">8</option>
                <option name="minMessage">fos_user.new_password.short</option>
                <option name="groups">
                    <value>MyChangePassword</value>
                </option>
            </constraint>
        </property>
    </class>
</constraint-mapping>
```

And to make it active I modified `config.yml` and added

```
fos_user:
    ...
    change_password:
            form:
                validation_groups: [MyChangePassword, Default]
```

However when I try to change my password via the resetting link, even if it doesn't respect the constraint, it changes my Password.

Do you know what I've made wrong? In `config.yml` I also tried to do the same with `resetting` instead of `change_password`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what where the problems.

First in `config.yml` the right line was `resetting` and not `change_password` as I'm using the resetting password functionality.

```
#var/www/MyProject/app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    ...
    resetting:
            form:
                validation_groups: [MyChangePassword, Default]
```

The other error was on the class name in `MyUsersBundle/Resources/config/validation.xml`. I didn't need to use`FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` instead of  `FOS\UserBundle\Form\Model\ChangePassword`.

```
#/MyProject/src/MyUsersBundle/Resources/config/validation.xml
<constraint-mapping xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping
        http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping/constraint-mapping-1.0.xsd">
    <!--
 ! Password Constraint
 !-->
    <class name="FOS\UserBundle\Model\User">
        <property name="plainPassword">
<constraint name="Length">
                <option name="min">8</option>
                <option name="minMessage">fos_user.new_password.short</option>
                <option name="groups">
                    <value>MyChangePassword</value>
                </option>
            </constraint>
        </property>
    </class>
</constraint-mapping>
```